# How MS-Bookings calendar meeting data save in SharePoint online List using Automate?

Tags: power-automate, flow, powerapp

I have Bookings shared calendar, If anyone book any meeting using that calender I want the booking details in the SharePoint list.
Like

Booking Title.
Booking Time.
Start date.
End Date.
Attendees.
category.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Power Automate Flow where:

- Trigger: **Microsoft Bookings - When a appointment is Created**
  [image]
- Action: **SharePoint "Create item"**
  [image]